# How can I display a class with no test data?

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the departments saved in the responding database with no students allocated to a department. I have the following code, the error message is displaying correctly but the list of departments with no students is not.

```
private static void displayDepartments(University u)
{
    foreach (Department d in u.Departments)
    {
          if (d.contains(null))
          {
              Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("All departments contain students");
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Departament` class? You most likely want to print each of its properties. Or parhaps the ToString is throwing an exception, what error are you getting and what code is in the Tostring()?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based in the clarified question (read comments on other answer).

```
bool errors = false;
foreach (Department d in u.Departments)
     if (d.students.Count == 0) // students is IList<> it has a property Count
     {
          Console.WriteLine(d.name); // name is string
          errors = true;
     }

if (!errors)
    Console.WriteLine("All departments contain students");
```

**First answer based on not accurate information:**

Since your Department class is IEnumerable you will be able to do something like this:

```
bool emptyDep = true;
foreach (Department d in u.Departments)
{
      if (!d.Any())
      {
          emptyDep = true;
          Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
      }
}

if (!emptyDep)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All departments contain students")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am still receiving an error from 'Any'

Comment: @user3452374 Include namespace System.Linq

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work...

```
private static void displayDepartments(University u)
{
    foreach (Department d in u.Departments)
    {
          if (d.students.Count == 0)
          {
          Console.WriteLine(d.name.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
          Console.WriteLine("All departments contain students");
          }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi, Thanks. However this gives me an error saying department does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrEmpty'

Comment: Hmmm... try casting it as a string first: 
     (string)d.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: @bGraves I don't think that Department is inherited from String. Besides IsNullOrEmpty is an static method of String class.

Comment: @agarwaen You are right. Finally managed to get to my IDE and start actually looking at code. Shouldn't answer questions before coffee I guess.

User3452374: were is the data actually coming from? and how is a non-null value displayed? IE, If you print a list of non-empty values, does it work?

Comment: @bGraves i have entered test data into my code, so i want display a list of departments that don't have any test data (i.e students) assigned to it. The department is the aggregated part class.

Comment: How is that data stored? Based on your explanation I would assume there is a department.name field, as well as a department.students<students> list held within the department object. That is where your answer is going to be, Right now you are trying to check the null status of the entire department object, where you actually wanted to look for a null value within the list of students that are in the department.

Comment: @bGraves yes i have a department.depCode, any idea what i need to do with this?

Comment: Not without knowing all of the details of how your code fits together. We need to know exactly what is inside the department object. I have the suspicion that you may actually only be pulling part of the data you need into the object, but I'm not sure. What else is in a department object, and what data types are they? :)

Comment: okay, i have the following...
string name
string depCode
string depNumber
and IList<Student> students

Comment: Edited my original answer with new potential solution

Comment: Sorry, Also changed d.toString() to d.name.tostring()

Comment: I am still receiving the error message that 'count' does not contain definition

Comment: hmmm... Try d.students.Any();
Your ilist should have some sort of capability to get the total number of students in it. Have you successfully gotten a list of students out of it at all?

Comment: yes within another method, this one just doesn't seem to be happening

Comment: @user3452374 I recommend changing `count` to `Count` and `d.name.ToString()` to `d.name` in the answer above.

Comment: @agarwaen thank you! that works finally! however, it displays the error message for as many departments that have students, i only want this to display once, any ideas?

Comment: @user3452374 Read my answer. After read all comments I changed it with the right code.

Comment: @user3452374 if it was useful please vote and accept the answer.